# Realm not initializing object

Tags: android, realm

I have a custom object named User, which is a RealmObject.

When I query my Realm DB for a user like this:

```
User user = getRealm().where(User.class).findFirst();
```

I get this response (using debugging):

[image: Realm Object]

As can be seen, the object isn't initialized but the values are showing in the first line.

What is the issue here?

Comment: The question you linked doesn't really provide a solution in my use case. I'm editing the question.

Comment: I mean, you really didn't specify that you're getting this during JSON serialization, before editing the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48550707/how-to-use-a-realmobject-with-moshi