# How to use a RealmObject with Moshi

Tags: android, realm, retrofit, moshi

I have a custom object named User, which is a RealmObject. This object also has annotations for Moshi because I plan on using this object in a retrofit call.

```
public class User extends RealmObject
{
    @PrimaryKey private long id;
    @Json(name = "email") private String email;
    @Json(name = "first_name") private String firstName;
    @Json(name = "last_name") private String lastName;
    @Json(name = "password_hash") private String passwordHash;
    @Json(name = "avatar") private String avatar;
    @Json(name = "phone_number") private String phoneNumber;
    @Json(name = "country") private String country;
    @Json(name = "city") private String city;
    @Json(name = "address") private String address;
    @Json(name = "location") private Location location;
    @Json(name = "zip") private String zip;
    @Json(name = "device_meta") private DeviceMeta deviceMeta;
}
```

When I query my Realm DB for a user like this:

```
User user = getRealm().where(User.class).findFirst();
```

I get this response (using debugging):

[image: Realm Object]

As can be seen, the object isn't initialized but the values are showing in the first line.

What is the issue here?

When I pass the above object as a @Body parameter, it appears to be empty.

I've also checked via Fiddler and the request sent to the server contains an empty object.

Question: How do I get this object to get the proper values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It likely has the proper values assuming you're saving and querying correctly.  Realm creates a subclassed version of each extended `RealmObject` as a "RealmProxy" object, and sometimes the in the debugger it doesn't look like what you would expect.  You'll notice that your class is actually showing up as `UserRealmProxy` (but it's inline values aren't null after User = ...).

To view the non-realm proxy version, you would have to use `Realm.copyFromRealm(...)`.

Also, note that anything parsed from the network won't be added to Realm automatically -- you have to explicitly copy to realm in this case to get the values on later queries, since things parsed in from the network are unmanaged initially.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your reply. You've solved my problem. copyFromRealm properly initialized the values in my object.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Done. I'm curious about how this works (even after reading a very detailed answer here on stack). If I call the getters, I get proper values. But if I pass the same object to retrofit, it is unable to get any values out of it.

Does retrofit use some other method to access values?

Comment: Might be worth opening up a separate question on that detailing it more specifically, since you'd need to provide more around your implementation details for the retrofit request.  In my experience, I haven't had any issues using managed/unmanaged objects interchangeably in your described use-case.  It could potentially be an issue around how moshi is serializing on the subclass because of the annotations, but I use Gson generally so I'd have to dive deeper.

Comment: Moshi has Reflection to read the values directly from the fields, but managed RealmProxy classes only read the data when you call an accessor

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Reflection is why Moshi fails to get anything out of a RealmObject.

Answer (score 2):

Please reconsider this design.

Using the same types for local persistence and networking saves some boilerplate code. As your application grows in complexity this approach may become quite fragile.

Creating a basic value object, UserJson, and a JSON adapter to map between is not much code. With Moshi’s @ToJson/@FromJson methods it's also quite easy and even testable. This will give you lots of flexibility in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You're suggest separate objects for Realm and Moshi? And then using toJson on the result I obtain from Realm?

Comment: You can use a separate object to represent the JSON model, but get Moshi to automatically convert into your preferred Realm type using it's adapter methods feature.